# “Analogous” vs. “analogical”

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

What is the difference in meaning between *analogous* and *analogical*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

“Analogous” means “comparable or similar”. For example, “most clothing worn by humans is analogous to a peacock's feathers: useless except for social signalling”.

“Analogical” means “of or pertaining to an analogy”, and is close in meaning to “metaphorical”. For example:

- “Many common English sayings are analogical in nature.”
- “While her statement was intended to be taken literally, many in the audience mistakenly believed it was analogical.”
- “Great scientists have used analogical thinking to notice the underlying relationships between natural phenomena.”

Comment: Thanks, I understand 'analogous', but I'm still a bit not clear about 'analogical'. Could you maybe give some examples?

Comment: “Great scientists have used analogical thinking to notice the underlying relationships between natural phenomena.”

“While her statement was intended to be taken literally, many in the audience mistakenly believed it was analogical.”

Comment: These examples would be a good addition to the answer, especially the latter one.

Comment: Good idea, I've updated the answer.