# Pertaining to "Analog(ue)"

Tags: analogy, technology

As *digitally* is to **digital**, is *analogously* or *analogically* to **analog(ue)**?

Comment: I believe this post answers your question:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112149/analogous-vs-analogical